# Encapsulating fields while creating classes in Netbeans

Tags: java, class, oop, netbeans, encapsulation

What will be the effect if we give ENCAPSULATE FIELDS and What will be the effect if we don't give the ENCAPSULATE FILEDS

[image]

Comment: Why don't you try?

Answer (score 0):

The point of encapsulation, is so that you can provide explicit algorithm for how a variable gets updated. For example, if you just allow other classes to update a variable directly:

```
var1 = 123;
```

... then you are stuck with those other classes being able to just update your class' variables without any control over what value is assigned or if any other variables should be updated as a consequence of that variable being updated.

But if you declare your variables to be `private` and provide a `public` accessor to `get` and `set` your variables' values, then you have ultimate control over how those variables are updated.

For example, you might have two variables related to each other. If one variable is updated then the other should be updated, too. Perhaps you have two variables, `var1` and `var2` (both declared `private`, of course, so no other class can access them directly). Maybe `var2` should always be a sum of 5 more than the value of `var1`. So when `var`1 is updated, using a `setter` (encapsulation) you can enforce this requirement:

```
void setVar1(int val) {
    var1 = val;
    var2 = val + 5;
}
```

And the inverse, setting `field2` subtracts 5 from `field1`:

```
void setVar2(int val) {
    var2 = val;
    var1 = val - 5; 
}
```

You could also constrain the values of these variables to be a specific range of values, like from 10 to 200 (for whatever reason). You could check the value being passed in to the setter and throw an exception, `IllegalArgumentException`, with an exception message that explains what rule was violated: `Value of var1 must be >= 5 <= 200`.

This is just a simple example of why encapsulation is *good* and should be practiced when writing Java code (or any OOP type language) and why most IDEs will automate the generation of these setters and getters for you.

You can [learn more about encapsulation here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you **tick that column**, NetBeans will set **all access levels of declared variables** to **private**.

Read more about **access levels** [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).